# Action column text issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs6

I have a grid **(ExtJs 6)** which extends from `'Ext.grid.Panel'`

I am having one action column in this grid which is defined as follows-

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    menuDisabled: true,
    text: 'ActionCol Header',
    sortable: false,
    items: [
       { iconCls: 'somecls', xtype: 'button', handler: 'somehandler' }
    ]
}
```

Here everything works fine except for the text of column.
The column header displays as expected i.e. 'ActionCol Header' but the text of this column is displaying as '*Actions*' in the column list which is used to hide/show columns (on click of column menu)

What I am doing wrong here? I tried to add `header: undefined` but its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For action columns the header text should be set via [**menuText**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-menuText) property even if it states that it takes the **text** property. Maybe thats a bug.

Comment: Yes, this definitely is a bug - either the source or the documentation is wrong. Please do not forget to report this bug in the official sencha forum.